# Angular and d3.js cannot access class field

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I want to make an app using charts in angular using svg and I also found that d3.js could be a big help in it. But first I reduced the code, because a simple d3.select(..).on(click) does not work well. I am fairly new to typescript as well.

**Here is the html:**

```
<button id="button1" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onButton1()">
Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" class="btn btn-danger">Button 2</button>
<br>
<svg width="1000" height="500" style="background-color: aqua"></svg>
```

**And the .ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from "d3";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  user_id:number = 1;

  ngOnInit(){

    d3.select("#button2")
      .on("click", this.onButton2);

  }

  onButton1(){
    console.log("button 1 was clicked, user_id: " + this.user_id);
  }

  onButton2(){
    console.log("button 2 was clicked, user_id: " + this.user_id);
  }

}
```

On the console:
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.

app.component.ts:22 button 1 was clicked, user_id: 1

app.component.ts:26 button 2 was clicked, user_id: undefined

From the d3.select... binding the method does not access the class filed, what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you adding event dynamically. and that is the problem its loosing its `this` reference.

`this` will be different for both `d3` and `Angular`

I would suggest try not use dynamic event binding, better use `click` event and pass `$event`

[checkout this post hope it helps](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/integrating-d3js-with-angular-5-0-848ed45a8e19)